# Why does Thanos want everybody to meet back at Titan?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

After getting the Space Stone in *Avengers: Infinity War*, Thanos again sends his minions to retrieve stones (that course of action in the past failed) and meet back at Titan.

For what purpose?  If the last Stones are on earth, why not just meet there?

Comment: because It's always comes onto **home sweet home**?

Comment: He left the charger cable for his video camera on the kitchen counter, so he needed to go back to capture the event on selfie-video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snapping his finger carries consequences for the whole universe, it does not matter where he does it. So, might as well do it "at home".

Just some thoughts on why he (might have) wanted to do it on titan

- Titan is his home planet. Maybe he wanted to end his quest at the place where it began / where he came up with his plan.
- for Thanos the earth has no special meaning, it is a random planet which happened to own 2 of the stones
- had they succeeded, the minions would have been way faster at retrieving the two stones. So they would have been forced to spend more time on earth which could have lead to some problems, for example the people from earth attacking them and the minions having to defend themselves

  - those are unnecessary risks on Thanos' side to lose his people
  - also there would be unnecessary casualties on the earth's side (... well... I guess he probably does not really care about some dead earthlings, but I could be wrong)
- the master does not follow the minions, they go to him

Answer (score -1):

I think that Thanos wanted to meet back in Titan so he could resurrect his planet and his own people with the Time and Soul Stones like he did with The Vision before he snap.

Comment: Why do you think that?  This seems unsupported by the source material.

Answer (score -4):

Thantos was born disfigured and exiled for his disfigurement because I guess the Titans believe in purity of DNA so l that's where he gained the name the Mad Titan and was exiled so he might want to returned to Titan to claim Revenge against his race

Comment: Titan is already dead and desolate. There's no revenge to be had.

Comment: 1) Titan is already destroyed. 2) Nowhere in the movies at any point does it say any of what you are claiming.